# issue with $ajax async false

Tags: ajax, bing-maps

I have this code:

```
 for(var i in dataJson){    
            direcc=dataJson[i].dir  ; 
            id=dataJson[i].id   ;

    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=' + direcc + '&key=mykey&jsonp=?',
           dataType: 'json',
       async: false,
           success: function(result) {

             loc = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates;
             direcc=result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.formattedAddress;
             lat=loc[0];
             long=loc[1];


          $("#bing").append('latitudeBing:' + lat + '<p>longitudeBing:' + long+'$$$$$$'+id);
 }
   });
```

The problem is that I want to write latitude+longitude+ id, but when it writes the id is the last for all of them ( id goes from 1-200, and in all coordinates appears 200).

The original function was $getjson and i changed it to make the $ajax call async:false, but that doesn't fix my problem.

Could anybody help me please? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited with the *correct* answer now.

[Fiddle to show the concept](http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/2Q3xD/1/)

```
for(var i in dataJson){    
    var direcc = dataJson[i].dir; 
    var id = dataJson[i].id;
    makeAjaxCall(direcc, id);
}

function makeAjaxCall(direcc, id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=' + direcc + '&key=mykey&jsonp=?',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            loc = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates;
            direcc=result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.formattedAddress;
            lat=loc[0];
            long=loc[1];
            $("#bing").append('latitudeBing:' + lat + '<p>longitudeBing:' + long+'$$$$$$'+id);
        }
    });
}
```

This puts the "current" `direcc` and `id` in the scope of the `makeAjaxCall` function.  The Fiddle I added is just showing how.

Also, no need to keep the `async: false,` around, so feel free to remove that if you want.

Comment: Yes, that's what i want to do. But I've added var in the declaration of the id, as you say but it still doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  Now that I look it over again, it will keep getting reset.  I updated my answer with a solution that works.

Comment: Yes it works!!! they doesn't appear in order..but i don't cara because what i need is that coordinates and id match, and they do it! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Yeah, order won't be guaranteed.  I forgot to mention, you should be able to remove the `async: false,` from your `.ajax` call.